Component with deferred props
I'm trying to build a dynamic system to match patterns to components, and I have something like this:
    {
        pattern: "xyz",
        element: <XyzLinks />,
        children:
        [
                {
                    pattern: /\d/,
                    element: <XyzLevelLinks level={???} />
                }
        ]
    }

If the pattern is xyz, I want to use component <XyzLinks />, and if the pattern is xyz/123, then I want to use <XyzLevelLinks level=123 />
But I can't define the component as shown above because I don't know the level until after the string has been parsed and I know what the level is.
What would be a way to define the component to use, but pass in the props after the component has been created?

Sorry but I didn't understand

I don't think creating a component is the way to go here. It sounds like you might need a hook of some sort which returns the right component depending on the input. You can use the createElement function to recursively populate the children of the component, as you build the component tree from the input. Speaking of input, I'm not sure what the input is supposed to be here

It was a bit difficult to understand your question, but I think I understand what you're asking.
Fundamentally, the answer is that in React, a component is simply fancy syntax for a function.
So, you could define your data structure like this:
{
    pattern: "xyz",
    element: <XyzLinks />,
    children:
    [
            {
                pattern: /\d/,
                element: (props) => <XyzLevelLinks level={props.level} />
            }
    ]
}

Then, whatever context has the pattern, will recieve the value of element with the function value here, which is a valid React component. It then has the context to provide the same numeric pattern to the component.
Here's a complete example of creating a dynamic component based on a function call:
import React from 'react';

function giveMeAnH (num) {
  return {
    1:  (props) => <h1>{props.message}</h1>,
    2:  (props) => <h2>{props.message}</h2>,
    3:  (props) => <h3>{props.message}</h3>,
    10: (props) => <span>hey there is no such thing! fine: {props.message}</span>
  }[num];
}

export function App(props) {
  MyNewH = giveMeAnH(3);
  AnotherHForMe = giveMeAnH(1);
  IsThisAnH = giveMeAnH(10);
  
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      
      <MyNewH message="wow" />
      <AnotherHForMe message="amazing" />
      <IsThisAnH message="nice" />
    </div>
  );
}

